# jQuery $.animate scrollLeft not working/Different methods?

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-animate

I'm having a bit of trouble with this.

Is this not the syntax?:

```
$("iframe#myFrame").animate({scrollLeft:"100px"},"slow");
```

I need to know exactly how to do this. Would you put `scrollLeft` in quotes as well?
You can see how clueless I am on jQuery animation. 
Do you also use px after your integer?

Now, if you'll notice, I've used my selector example as an iframe.

Maybe jQuery animation `scrollLeft` doesn't work on an iframe?

If that is the case, what are some other methods for scrolling an `iframe` at say, the `click` of an HTML button? I've tried `scrollLeft()`, but maybe I have the syntax wrong with that as well.

Please give me specific examples that clearly show a general and simple syntax of your methods at going about this problem.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? You want to animate the iframe container to move all to the left by 100px? Or do you want to scroll the iframe content to the left by 100px?

Comment: I wish to scroll the frame by 100px

Comment: The iframe content? (by scrolling it´s understood to move the content.. just as if you were scrolling the page with your trackpad or mouse)

Comment: Yep. What I want to do is hide the iframe scrollbars, and have users be able to scroll the frame either left or right with the click of a button.

Comment: Ok I see. So the buttons will be outside the iframe container, then you want to access the iframe and scroll the content.

Comment: Yep. So what exactly is the general syntax to scroll the iframe left and right?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the selector is incorrect. Try to give your `<iframe>` an id and use it on the selector. For example:

```
<iframe id = 'myframe'>.
```

Your jquery script must to be like this:

```
$('#myframe').animate();
```